# Create Transparent Mainscreen in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i want to create a type of `MainScreen` in my `Blackberry app` which should be `Transparen/Translucent`.
I tried with following code on `MyCustomMainScreen's` constructor but it still shows a white screen

```
Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 50);
this.setBackground(bg);
```

I have read in the forum and also tested it for popup screens and it works fine with them but fails with `mainscreens`. 
Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this for MainScreen..?

-Big O

Answer (score 3):

override the paint method like:

```
class M extends MainScreen
{
        public M() 
        {
            setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE, 100));
            LabelField l=new LabelField("hello");
            add(l);
        }
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
        {
            super.subpaint(graphics);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek this was really helpful, however when i added 3 HorzontalFieldManagers (HFMs), each one in-turn having aBitMapField, to the screen and scroll it, the BitmapField Images leave trails and looks bad. Any idea how to handle that..?

Comment: Use invalidate() method in paint() method of HorzontalFieldManager.

Comment: Vivek, i tried calling invalidate() in paint() method of the HFM holding up my BitMapFields, but it does not even scroll after that. seems like a cycle, as soon as it paints and  calls invalidate()  from paint() method which causes it to call paint() again in turn.

Comment: You have a scroll problem or image drawing problem? If scroll problem, then use style VERTICAL_SCROLL.

Comment: this is not Scroll problem, as all UI elements  are visible with in screen boundry. However on device like torch it still scrolls across the UI elements little bit using  trackpad and comes back again, this leaves some trails of Bitmaps i am using there.

Comment: You can open this issue in separate thread and marked solved this thread. So other user also see your problem, because without code analyse the problem is difficult.

Comment: Found another solution to the problem. which seems to solve the image cracking issue on the screen. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902007/use-of-subpaint-on-mainscreen-doesnt-paint-child-correctly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 50);
this.setBackground(bg);
```

maybe better

```
Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 50);
getMainManager().setBackground(bg);
```

Comment: without overriding the paint() method. getMainManager().setBackground(bg); don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution without overriding the `paint` method. You need to set the background full transparent for the Screen and translucent for the main manager:

```
// Full transparent background
setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0));

// Manager translucent background
getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 50));
```