# Use of subpaint() on Mainscreen Doesn't paint child correctly

Tags: blackberry

To get a quick background of the problem please refer to 
[Create Transparent Mainscreen in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659649/create-transparent-mainscreen-in-blackberry)
.

The problem I am facing is with painting of the child on mainscreen.
I wanted my mainscreen to look transparent/translucent as an original requirement and add my other UI elements e.g. managers/field on top of it.

So the UI elements I am using are 3 BitmapField(s) which should have its thick border created using BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder() with two colors added for Field.VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS  and Field.VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL states. all of these BitmapFields are added in their respective HorizontalFieldManger which in turn are added to the screen.

So part of the problem is, when I do navigation across these BitmapFields, "some area" of the border added to the BitmapFields doesn't get painted as per the state (normal, focus) specified.

Other problem is, on torch 9800 when I navigate across from top to bottom or vice versa,  i see default scroll happening which should be normal however on each scroll my BitmapField leaves some tail/crack on the screen when movement happened on the scrolling.

None of such things happen when I use normal screen (not use subpaint to make the screen transparent).

Do you have any idea what's happening here..?

- Big O

Comment: I've read both of your questions, and I don't understand what a transparent mainscreen is.  What do you want to see where the 'transparency' is?  There's nothing behind the mainscreen for the transparency to let through.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for you your question. my application has a default mainscreen and i allow user to go to a new screen by letting him choose an option through the menu. The new mainscreen which user chooses, should show its content however at the same time user should be able to see the content of old/previous screen. for this to happen new screen should have transparency to let user see through. hope this help –

Comment: hmmm.... doesn't the BB only issue paint commands to the top most screen on the stack?  So any pixels that get obscured on the underlying screen (really just a residual bitmap) would not get repainted?

Comment: yes BB issues paint command to the top most  screen on the stack but the pixels that get obscured in this case are not of the underlying screen rather its of the current topmost screen (transparent screen)

Answer (score 1):

YMMV, but I've made a transparent screen with this:

```
public class TranslucentScreen extends Screen {
    public TranslucentScreen() {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL));
        setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0x000000, 150));
    }
    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        setPosition(0, 0);
        setExtent(width, height);

        setPositionDelegate(0, 0);
        layoutDelegate(width, height);
    }
}
```

This was for a basic popup screen screen I made that had a semi-transparent black background. I added a VerticalFieldManager to the screen that I controlled the background painting on so it would be how I wanted it, and then added my other Fields to that.

Comment: Awesome.. seems to be working for me. I apologize that i am not able to vote you up as i don't have minimal reputation :P

Comment: No worries, just glad to help out!